# Google Maps Distances and Travel time not always accurate

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having a bit of trouble with this script i've made - essentially its a script with parses a CSV and using the data in the CSV - builds a list of town names, and associated markers in a Google Map. Each marker as an info window that pops up which contains some information, like local councils, tourism links etc. It also contains distance and travel time information which uses Google's Get Distance Matrix as shown here (you can see the context in which this snippet is used in the CodePen below):

```
service.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins: [whereIsUser],
    destinations: [new google.maps.LatLng(results.data[i][5], results.data[i][6])],
    travelMode: 'DRIVING',
    drivingOptions: {
        departureTime: timeInMs,
        trafficModel: 'optimistic'
    },
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
}, function (response, status) {
    if (status !== 'OK') {
        console.log('Error was: ' + status);
    } else {
        theDistance.push(response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text);
        theDuration.push(response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text);
    }
});
```

I've attached a CodePen below - for a working example you can go here too https://codepen.io/markorapaic/live/yoVVQb

See the Pen [DRH Town Map](https://codepen.io/markorapaic/pen/yoVVQb/) by Marko Rapaic ([@markorapaic](https://codepen.io/markorapaic)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

The distance and travel time is based either on the user's location if they choose to enable location tracking in their browser of choice, or alternatively Adelaide, South Australia. Basically what's happening is that when the script / page initially loads, if you click around and check out some locations, the distances are way off and the travel times aren't exactly the same as the ones estimated by Google Maps. However if you load the page again afterwards, the distances become stable and accurate, and the travel time becomes stable but still inaccurate.

Basically just wondering if (a) anyone knows why this issue might be happening and how I can either minimise the inaccuracies or remove them altogether, and (b) if there's a better way I could implement this entire solution. Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: Just bumping this, would love to get some feedback :)

Comment: The sample code seems to be broken. I can see a lot of exceptions in browser console.

Comment: Hi xomena - do you mind providing a screenshot of the errors? I'm not seeing any on my side. Edit - i'm checking in Chrome dev tools.

Comment: I can see something like this http://imgur.com/a/wVvHH